# Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON express ejs

Tags: javascript, html, express, passport.js, ejs

I've been searching for this problem on Google for a while now and can't seem to understand the issue. I am using ejs. It does work when I manually type it on the address bar `localhost:3000/home` this works, but using passport.js and setting home as my successRedirect, just gives me an error including the failureRedirect.

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs")
app.use(express.static("views"))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.get("/home", (_, res) => res.render("home"))
app.get("/login", (_, res) => res.render("login"))
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/home",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true,
}))
```

```
const response = await fetch("/login", {
    method: "POST",
    body: {
        [username.id]: usernameValue,
        [password.id]: passwordValue,
    },
})

const result = await response.json()

if (result.id) localStorage.setItem("loginId", result.id)
if (result.href) window.location.href = result.href
```

I expected it to show the home page.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE` is the beginning of an HTML or XML file.

Comment: This error shows when you're passing non-JSON content to JSON.parse()

This will fail: JSON.parse("<html>"); and this will pass: JSON.parse("{}");

Comment: I know even removing this wouldn't do anything. It would still give me an error like <h1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I'm so dumb. The problem was, I was parsing the result from fetch, which was trying to convert the html file to JSON.

```
fetch("/login", {
    method: "POST",
    body: {
        [username.id]: usernameValue,
        [password.id]: passwordValue,
    },
}).then((response) => window.location.replace(response.url))
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
app.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/home",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true,
}),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Comment: Hi. This is considered a 'code only' answer, and we don't really like them on SO. It woul.d be better if you could take a little more time explaining to the OP what they did wrong and why your code remedies the problem. Thanks.